# getLastError after collection drop in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

Through mongo-java-driver, I call `DBCollection`'s  `drop() method to drop the collection.

If I want to ensure that the collection has been dropped indeed, can I use `getLastError(WriteConcern concern)` just after `drop()`?

*Drop* is a kind of *write* in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of `getLastError` when you call it after `drop()`?  If it doesn't work, you could always check that `count()` called on the collection returns `0`.